# Path that do not work under IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I lost 6 hours because I thought it was bug in my code. But no. IIS 10.0 Express do not allow POST when path is:

```
/api/cashier/v1/authentication/signin
```

Why? Why? Why?

PS 1

The same code (path) works fine under full IIS.

PS 2

Where I can find iisexpress compiled assemblies? There is no any files in global temp or %TEMP%\iisexpress\ASP Compiled Templates.

I have VS2015 Update 2.

Comment: Works with host name very well (I'm removing that part of path from question). I'm using this that way couple of years but problem like above I see first time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IISExpress checks physical path first, before mvc comes to run. Unfortunately I have the same structure of folders like virtual path (/api/cashier/v1/authentication/signin).

Changing physical folder named API to WebApi resolves problem.

Second solution i change routes.RouteExistingFiles to true but then every request (static files) will be handled by mvc.